# Peformance of using Inner Join within leftjoin v.s. multiple leftjoins

Tags: mysql, performance, left-join

I have a question about MySQL performance

Query1:

```
select departments.*, booth_feature.some_feature
from departments
left join booth on booth.dept_id = departments.dept_id
left join booth_feature  on  booth.booth_id=booth_feature.booth_id
```

Query2:

```
select departments.*, booth_feature.some_feature
from departments
left join (booth, booth_feature) on ( booth.dept_id = departments.dept_id and booth.booth_id=booth_feature.booth_id)
```

Assuming: 
department can have multiple booths

1 booth => 1 booth feature

both department and booth tables are big tables.

Using explain, the first query seems to be better (it checks on booth before booth_feature), despite the fact that left join is generally more expensive than inner join. Is that right?

Comment: I see left joins in both statements - what is the meaning of the () after the left join in query 2?

Comment: I need some data from the booth_feature table. (added to the select now) and the () after left join is to link booth_feature and booth together

Comment: I see, the parens are a non-standard syntax denoting an inner/cross join.  I prefer standard syntax to keep things simple for my brain ;)  So you're asking if we disagree with the explain plan?  Things may happen differently at different times, for different data and indexes, but if it's not a huge difference in performance and you have a representative testing set, you're probably don't need to worry about it too much.

Comment: Query 2 seems like a better logical choice to me (easier to read?) if I have multiple tables chained after booth and not related to departments. That's why I was curious if there is a performance difference.  Inside of the parens I am basically using Inner Join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically doing a full cross join between booth and booth_feature in the second query, if these tables grow large, this have the potential of being quite costy. And the optimizer wont have a way of intelligently joining 'departments' with the cross product since it needs to calculate the full cross product before its able to join it with departments. Due to the lack of a join clause (making it a full cross product).

in the first query, the optimizer can use indexes from departments and booths, and then use a reference (REF type in the MYSQL EXPLAIN output) from that result (based on both indexes) into another index (of booth_features)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So even with booth.dept_id = departments.dept_id, booth and booth_feature still do a cross join?

Comment: Yes. The brackets around (booth, booth_feature) explicitly tells mysql that you want it to evaluate that join before the LEFT JOIN. And the join clause you are quoting is the clause for the LEFT JOIN. So at the time booth.dept_id = departments.dept_id is evaluated, the (booth, booth_feature) cross product will already have been created :)